# I cannot parse a JavaScript rendered webpage with Python Requests

Tags: python, parsing, request, get

I tried to write a little app for parsing this page: https://apps.microsoft.com/store/category/Business

I cannot get a full html code. The tag body is not full.

```
import requests


def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }

    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    with open("index.html", "w") as file:
        file.write(req.text)

get_data("https://apps.microsoft.com/store/category/Business")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just parse this page because it is a client side rendered page through JavaScript.

You need to use a tool like:

- [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer)
- [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io)

Or maybe try to reverse engineer the page and directly call the APIs.

(Or maybe see if Microsoft has a public API you can call to get the info you want).